# How to pass data from the selected row in data grid view to a label of another form

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

I have a datagridview in form1 and and labelboxes on another form. what i want to do is whenever a row is selected in form1 all of its data will be displayed on form 2 using labelboxe. Meaning, each column of the selected row will be distributed to its appropriate label box.

Answer (score 2):

There are several ways to do something like this. Here are two ways to pass data:

In Form2 you need to make a second constructor that will take two objects :

```
public partial class Form2 : Form
    {
        public Form2()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }


        public string yourName { get; set; }
        public int Age { get; set; }

        public Form2(string name, int age)
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            yourName = name;
            Age = age;

        }

        private void Form2_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            label1.Text = yourName;
            label2.Text = Age.ToString();
        }
    }
```

In Form1, you create an Instance of Form2, and pass objects :

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Form2 F2 = new Form2("Jon Smith", 33);

            this.Hide();
            F2.ShowDialog();

        }
    }
```

Or you can do it this way :

On form 2 you need to set your labels modifier properties as public, as they will be by default be set to private. You can do this from the properties tab in Design Mode.

Once done, In form1 you can create an instance of Form2 and pass values over to the public labels :

```
Form2 f2 = new Form2();

f2.label1.text = datagridview1.currentRow.cells[0].value.tostring();

f2.ShowDialog();
```

Hope this helps.